# Unable to put view above navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to design a side menu, whose height would be equal to screen height (therefore hiding the navigation bar too). However I am unable to get the same.

I have put constraints as this:
[image]
 and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`
I have mentioned -         `sideMenuTopConstraint.constant = -1 * (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!`

However I see no change. Also by increasing the height of the side menu view in storyboard, I see that it is always below the nav bar. How do I make it appear above it?

Comment: You can use [SlideMenuController](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift)

Comment: Set the constant to -64 and see if that helps.  
Also, try moving your logic from viewDidLayoutSubviews to viewWillAppear(). This may be a timing issue. Lastly, use the Debug View Hierarchy tool to see what the constraint is becoming and make sure the constant is not 0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the view to **window** as a `subview`, that should bring this `view` above the navigation bar as needed.
This is because window is the root of all the views.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(desiredViewHere)
```